# How do I create a unique id for Map in Java?

Tags: java, uuid

I am looking for a correct way to create unique ID for Map based on map's contents. So,I expect IDs of 2 maps which contain the same data to  be the same as well and have as small chance of collisions as possible.

My current guess is using UUID, writing Map into Object and then building UUID from bytes.

```java
 Map map;
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut);

 out.writeObject(map);
 out.close();
 UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(byteOut.toByteArray());
```

However, I wanted to ask if this is the optimal way and if not what else should I try?

Comment: Yes, a UUID would seem to meet your requirements.  But, what is the point of generating a UUID as a key unless you would also be storing that key in some other data structure?  Can you give more background to your problem?

Comment: Should each element in the map have a unique ID or should the whole map have a unique id?

Comment: Your current example will work but I believe only when the map is identical.
Maps with the same content in a different order will likely result in a different UUID due to their toByteArray returning a different value.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer only the map itself

Comment: @DanielTung thanks, you are right, I totally missed it. That's not how it should be for sure, but I don't understand how to avoid that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are right, I need the ID to be used later to identify the map. Without going into details we can imagine it is for unique file naming for example. However, as it was pointed out here in comments, the IDs for maps with different order of same elements will be different, so my solution is wrong.

Comment: Not sure what your requirements actually are, but assuming that a UUID would always be a unique key is a good assumption.  There are roughly `1 x 10^50` possible UUID values.  This is ginormous, and you would rot away from old age before you would likely ever have a collision.

Comment: @DanielTung so, just sorting the map or using TreeMap should fix the problem it seems

Comment: I would say that directly serialising the map means you are bound to the particular flavour of Map you are using.  Maybe it would be better to sort the map as suggested and then iterate the `Entry`s performing a custom serialisation of those entries.  That way you are protected from changes to `TreeMap` and you control the serialisation format.  It looks like you are writing a kind of merkel tree.

Comment: What type will the keys and values in the map be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can use any suitable for your needs (in terms of collisions, performance) hash function, for example, SHA-1:

```
public class MainClas {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("1", 1);
        map.put("2", 2);
        map.put("3", 3);

        String mapString = map.entrySet().toString();
        System.out.println(mapString);

        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        byte[] hashBytes = digest.digest(mapString.getBytes());

        String hashString =  bytesToHex(hashBytes);

        System.out.println(hashString);
    }

    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] hashInBytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : hashInBytes) sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

output:

```
[1=1, 2=2, 3=3]
1a1677fe956c66c776a100b32b0a2b20fdabb5f3
```

P.S. you can minimize collisions by using a composite hash from hashes produced from different algorithms (2 or 3).

Comment: So, what you are suggesting is basically sha1? Then I could just use UUIDv5 since it uses SHA-1. I've seen several implementations but the default package does not include it. Do you think it is better than UUIDv3 that I am currently using? As far as I understand UUID has very small chance of collision so I am not sure if it is reasonable to generate it "manually"

Comment: @Luminous I suggest any SHA-* bc it is cryptographic. It is more stable in terms of hashes than md5 f.e. SHA-1 produces 20 bytes of hash. But UUID produces only 16 bytes and erase 2 bytes from 16 for setting version & variant. As a result, you have only 14 bytes hash in UUID VS 20 bytes SHA-1 which is not good and basically can produce even more collisions. To minimize possible collisions,  I would suggest not to use UUID at all and use a composite key produced from 2 or 3 different algorithms, like key = sha1(bytes) + sha256(bytes) or key = sha1(bytes) + sha256(bytes)+md5(bytes)

Comment: Then I should just forget about UUID5 since it cuts the result to shorter length and indeed use SHA-256 or smth like that. Do people always have to implement their own approach to ID generation in their systems? I was hoping there is one clear "good way", but seems like no. Thanks for so clear explanation!

Comment: @Luminous depends on the task and a variety of input. But it is good to think in advance and look under the hood. You are welcome :)

Comment: Please note that sha generated from [1=1, 2=2, 3=3] and [2=2, 1=1, 3=3] are different, even though the Maps are equal.